# Error Handling on external Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am just wondering if it would be possible to do error handling on an external macro. Basically what I want to achieve is I have have thousands of excel workbooks that come in daily and I want to open each of them and run the macro from them (easily done just use the Application.run feature )

```
Application.Run ("'" & ActiveWorkbook & "'!Export")
```

What I want to achieve is I want to run error resolving function if that external macro incurs an error.

This is what I have so far

```
Dim str_SearchFile, str_FileName, str_SearchPath As String
Dim wb_WorkBook As Workbook


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    str_ThisBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'Set the current workbook for later reference
        str_SearchPath = Sheets("Control Panel").Range("E2")
        str_SearchFile = Sheets("Control Panel").Range("E2") & "\*.xls*" 'Sets the file type to search for
        str_NextFile = Dir(str_SearchFile, vbDirectory) 'Sets the amount of files in the directory matching the criterea (.xls)

        Do While Len(str_NextFile) > 0
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wb_WorkBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=str_SearchPath & "\" & str_NextFile, Password:="")
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                Application.Run ("'" & str_NextFile & "'!Export")
                str_FileName = str_SearchPath & "\Done" & "\" & str_NextFile
                wb_WorkBook.Save
                wb_WorkBook.Close
                FileCopy (str_SearchPath & "\" & str_NextFile), str_FileName
                Kill (str_SearchPath & "\" & str_NextFile)
            End If
            str_NextFile = Dir
        Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Any Advise is very welcome!

Thank you in advance

Comment: If the workbooks you're processing all have the exact same macro, you could create a version of it in your processing workbook, and pass it a reference to the workbook you want it to operate on.  Then you can edit it to trap any errors, without needing to alter any of the code in the thousands of existing workbooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to get this to work the way you are trying.

The [MSDN on On Error Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx) indicates that it (emphasis added):

> Enables an error-handling routine and specifies the location of the
>   routine **within a procedure**; can also be used to disable an
>   error-handling routine.

The [VBE Glossary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264568.aspx) defines a procedure as:

> A named sequence of statements executed as a unit. For example,
>   Function, Property, and Sub are types of procedures. A procedure name
>   is always defined at module level. All executable code must be
>   contained in a procedure. Procedures can't be nested within other
>   procedures.

This means that calling error handling before calling the macro in the other book, will be ignored in the called macro (confirmed through testing).

The only way that you would be able to enable error handling would be to actually modify the code in the workbook prior to calling the macro... which is very complicated. For your reference, here is a webpage giving an [example of editing project code from VBA](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Self-Modifying-VBA.aspx).

Comment: It seems that I would have to do this "old school" and what do an error to appear then deal with it manually.

Comment: Right, unless you can get the workbook originators to fix the Export macro per John Bustos' recommendation. I think you should focus your efforts on that because having to sit and wait for errors is far less time efficient than just putting all the failed files in  a \Failed\ folder.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I would deal with this is to change your external workbook's "Export" sub into a function that returns a value - Say an integer.

What you can then do is put error trapping into that function and, based upon the outcome of the procedure it can return, say:

```
0 = All Went Well
1 = Failed to do XXX
2 = Failed to do YYY
```

You could then change your code to something like this:

```
Select Case Application.Run ("'" & str_NextFile & "'!Export")
Case 0
   MsgBox "All Went Well"

Case 1
   MsgBox "Failed to do XXX"

Case 2
   MsgBox "Failed to do YYY"

End Select
```

This will allow you to put the error trapping where it belongs and know how the procedure ran.

hope this helps

Comment: Interesting suggestion! I will look into this if I can maybe manipulate the external vba. Although it wasnt created by me hehe

Comment: This still requires the methods in the thousands of workbooks to be updated to trap their own errors for this to work.